# How to copy files from sdcard to isolated Storage in Wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a file let say image.jpg or file.txt  .. in my sdcard in wipdows phone 8 /8.1

Now  i want to copy that file in my isolated storage of my app .

Can it be done  ? If yes How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the [KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary.aspx) in order to access the files from your SD card.

These are some sample:

[Access the SD card in Windows Phone apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn611857.aspx)

[Reading from an SD Card in Windows Phone 8 Applications](http://www.developer.com/ws/reading-from-an-sd-card-in-windows-phone-8-applications.html)

You could use the `MemoryStream` to transfer the file to `IsolatedStorage` and then load it from there.

[Load File from SDCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406264/)

Comment: this link's example i tryed out earlier  but it is unable to detect files "http://www.developer.com/ws/reading-from-an-sd-card-in-windows-phone-8-applications.html "

Comment: The KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary doesn't work accesss permission denied